# build failed Google io 2018 (iosched)

Tags: android, gradle, googleio, iosched

Download the project of Google IO 2018 (iosched), try to compile it in Android Studio 3.3 Canary 7, also the probe in 3.2 RC1. But I get the following error:

```
error: resource style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored (aka com.google.samples.apps.iosched:style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored) not found.
```

Checking the file style. xml, it is observed that fails to find the style TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.IOSched.BottomNavigationView" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/google_sans</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/bottom_nav_item</item>
</style>
```

Also check that the Google Material components dependency if implemented.

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"
```

I can't understand why it might be making this mistake.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can see here
https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/285#issuecomment-416114763

you can use the [Android Studio Stable 3.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

use the last dependencies.

in the file iosched/gradle.properties,mofiy

```
androidGradlePluginVersion = '3.2.0'
materialVersion = '1.0.0'
kotlinVersion = '1.2.51'
```

in the file iosched/mobile/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

change

```
@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored
```

to

```
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored
```

Comment: I wonder why they don't update this kind of references while gradle plugin evolves...

Answer (score 0):

with Android Studio `3.1.4` it builds, unless updating the outdated dependencies. there also is on open issue: https://github.com/google/iosched/issues/285
and it does complain much when building with `./gradlew build`

once I've manually updated those `beta01` versions to `rc01` I also get that:

```
error: resource style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored (aka com.google.samples.apps.iosched:style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored) not found.
```

which basically means, that [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) is missing or outdated. to resolve this, you could simply copy the absent style from GitHub and manually add it into `styles.xml` or simply do not update that outdated library versions, until there is a final release of all those release candidates, which are not yet considered as "stable".

the bottom line may be, that it builds against `materialVersion = '1.0.0-beta01'` (which might contain that style), but not against `materialVersion = '1.0.0-rc01'` (which may lack that style).

maybe consider using a **stable** version of Android Studio, alike `3.1.4` - instead of using the canary channel and then complain it won't work; maybe you even build unknowingly against the `rc01` version, because this is **exactly** the issue which I get when updating that library to `rc01` - and the title of this question also boldly states `RC01`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem, because I'm trying to make the project compile without modifying any dependency.

Comment: only can tell that I can build the project with Android Studio `3.1.4` and Gradle `4.4` ...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it compile by installing android studio 3.2.0 beta 4.

as seen in the following image
[image]